# Power Query: how to keep file detail when importing from folder

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to import some files from a folder using Power Query, and struggling to include the circled date fields in the final dataset.

[Date Fields in file property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46WAX.jpg)

When I expand the "content" column, all other data fields are removed.

[All file properties are lost when I expand "content"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKNd6.jpg)

How do I keep the date field from file property?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are combining binaries (the double arrow action), which takes all of the text files and combines them together. As a result, it can't include the other columns in the source table.

I think what you want to do is to store the contents of the file as a text or list value in a column. You can get the text values by right-clicking on the Content column header and choosing Transform | Text.

You could also add a custom column and use a formula like `Text.FromBinary([Content])` or `Lines.FromBinary([Content])`. You can add a custom column by going to the Add Column ribbon tab and clicking on Add Custom Column.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alejandro. Sounds like I need to have clean data in the folder. The txt files are system extracts, I need to do further editing like column splitting, remove initial roles, remove nulls etc after expanding the content. I have done the edits in PowerQuery, then realised I also need the "creation date" from file property.

Comment: Following from my previous comment, just to clarify, so there is no way to keep the other fields when "combining binaries"? If the raw files are the way they are, is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: No, you cannot keep it. It wouldn't make sense since the combined binary has files from all of the dates.
If you use the second option, you could turn the list into a table and do modifications on the table in each cell. To make it easier, you could write the query against a table from one file, turn that query into a function that takes in a table, and then use that function in the formula for Add Custom Column to get tables in the shape that you want.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching for a solution this post helped me find it. I made a normal query from a file/folder then I deleted the step "Remove other columns" and replaced that step by manually removing al columns except for the date column I wanted to use.
Worked fine for me.